# Why middleware is getting called even when the mount path specified is not it's own?

Tags: node.js, express, middleware

I am new to node and express, trying to explore things. I made two middlewares both with their specified mount path, the MIDDLEWARE 2 is getting called even when the request is not for it.
The code written by me:

```
// middleware 1
app.use('/demo',function(req, res, next){
    console.log("MIDDLEWARE 1 CALLED");
    next();
});

// middleware 2
app.use('/', function(req, res, next){
    console.log("MIDDLEWARE 2 CALLED");
    next();
});

app.get('/demo',function(req, res){
    console.log("Hello, How are you?");
});
```

And now in the browser, I type: `localhost:8000/demo`
In console I am getting this:

```
MIDDLEWARE 1 CALLED
MIDDLEWARE 2 CALLED
Hello, How are you?
```

My question is when I specify the path in request as `/demo` why does the second middleware gets called?
However, when I type this: `localhost:8000`, it works as expected Only middleware 2 is called.
Where am I wrong in the first case?

Thanks in advance for any help you are able to provide.

Answer (score 2):

Express' `app.use` will apply to every request with a path that starts with your entered path. Meaning `app.use('/demo', ...)` will apply to every route that starts with /demo, and `app.use('/', ...)` will apply to every route that starts with /, which obviously is every route.

If you only want to have it on the exact / path, maybe `app.all('/', ...)` could solve your issue as it only applies to the exact match but still for all HTTP methods.

Comment: When I type `localhost:8000/demoCar`, The output in console is this:
`MIDDLEWARE 2 CALLED`
Why the middleware 1 is not getting called?

Comment: With starting with I mean where the first segment of the path is equal. If you would type ‘localhost:8000/demo/car’, it should get called as the first segment equals the path of middleware 1. You can also think of this as calling all sub-routes with the same parent when you use middleware.

Comment: Just one more thing, Does this happen with routers also? I mean if I write `app.get('/', functi...) ` and then also write `app.get('/demo', funct....)`. According to me, It doesn't happen in the case of routers as I have observed. Am I right?
And I'm sorry for being persistent on the same question

Comment: You're right, won't happen with direct routes like `app.get` or `app.all`. Only happens with middleware that you apply using `app.use`.